# Dynamically generated CURSOR in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, dynamic, plpgsql, database-cursor

I have got a cursor, it is pointing to a SELECT, but this select is generated dynamically. I want to assign the statement after the declarement.
I have done an example working and another example NOT working. This is a simple example to print some data only.
This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_columns (
  id      serial NOT NULL,
  "name"  varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  /* Keys */
  CONSTRAINT my_columns_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
  );

CREATE INDEX my_columns_index01
  ON public.my_columns
  ("name");


INSERT INTO public.my_columns
    ("name")
VALUES
    ('name1'),
    ('name2'),
    ('name3'),
    ('name4'),
    ('name5'),
    ('name6');
```

This is the function(I have put the working code and the code not working):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.dynamic_table
(
)
RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE
       v_sql_dynamic varchar;

       --NOT WORKING:
       --db_c CURSOR IS (v_sql_dynamic::varchar);

       --WORKING:
       db_c CURSOR IS (SELECT id, name from public.my_columns);

       db_rec RECORD;

BEGIN
     v_sql_dynamic := 'SELECT id, name from public.my_columns';
    FOR db_rec IN db_c LOOP

        RAISE NOTICE 'NAME: %', db_rec.name;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN 'OK';

EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN

    RETURN 'Error: ' || SQLERRM::text || ' ' || SQLSTATE::text;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you really need the explicit cursor? If you need iterate over dynamic SQL, then you can use `FOR IN EXECUTE`. It is loop over implicit (internal) cursor for dynamic SQL

```
FOR db_rec IN EXECUTE v_sql_dynamic
LOOP
  ..
END LOOP
```

Little bit more complex solution is described in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-cursors.html) - `OPEN FOR EXECUTE`:

```
do $$
declare r refcursor; rec record;
begin 
  open r for execute 'select * from pg_class'; 
  fetch next from r into rec;
  while found 
  loop
    raise notice '%', rec; 
    fetch next from r into rec; 
  end loop;
  close r; 
end $$;
```

With this kind of cursor, you cannot to use `FOR IN`

Comment: OPEN FOR EXECUTE is the one i need. Thanks

Comment: I believe you will also have to declare the rec variable: rec record;