# How do I create a personalized role in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I would like to create a personalized role for all the customers in the customers table of my db. I want the role name to look like client_first_name_last_name.
Also, the Customer's payment and rental history must not be empty.

I have tried
`CREATE ROLE (SELECT DISTINCT 'client_' || c.first_name || '_' || c.last_name FROM public.customer c);` but it doesn't seem to work

Is there a way to loop throught the table column and create a role for each customer?

Comment: you will need to use dynamic sql for that, with a cursor and loop

Comment: How do I do that? can you help me with some scripts or sample script?

Comment: a quick search finds you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495593/dynamically-generated-cursor-in-postgresql

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.